# Selecting posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm new to wordress and php.
I need to display all posts from june 2009 to june 2010.
How can I do that by creating a custom loop?

Answer (score 3):

query_posts() just allow to show posts from a specific week or month. However, you can show posts between two dates, adding a few lines of code. You need to paste this code wherever in your theme you'd like to display.

```
<?php
      function filter_where($where = '') {
            $where .= " AND post_date >= '2009-06-01' AND post_date <= '2010-06-30'";
        return $where;
      }
        add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
        query_posts($query_string);
        while (have_posts()) :
          the_post();
          the_content();
        endwhile;
    ?>
```

Source: http://bit.ly/i5zXP0

Answer (score 1):

Using WP Query
Time Parameters

year (int) - 4 digit year (e.g. 2011).
monthnum (int) - Month number (from 1 to 12).
w (int) - Week of the year (from 0 to 53). Uses the MySQL WEEK command. The mode is dependent on the "start_of_week" option.
day (int) - Day of the month (from 1 to 31).
hour (int) - Hour (from 0 to 23).
minute (int) - Minute (from 0 to 60).
second (int) - Second (0 to 60).
m (int) - YearMonth (For e.g.: 201307).

**Returns posts for just the current date:**

```
   $today = getdate();
   $query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $today["year"] . '&monthnum=' . $today["mon"] . '&day=' . $today["mday"] );
```

**Returns posts for just the current week:**

```
   $week = date('W');
    $year = date('Y');
    $query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&w=' . $week );
```

Return posts for March 1 to March 15, 2010:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
// posts for March 1 to March 15, 2010
$where .= " AND post_date >= '2010-03-01' AND post_date < '2010-03-16'";
return $where;
 }

 add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
 $query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
 remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

**Return posts 30 to 60 days old**

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
// posts  30 to 60 days old
$where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days')) . "'" . "    AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
return $where;
 }

 add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
 $query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
 remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

For more reference click here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query